# Json Decoder Error while trying to load using json.load inPython

Tags: python, json

[image: Image of what I am receiveing]I am trying to load a text file formatted as JSON using the below code

```
with open('orderdata/ETHUSDTorder.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    actualdata=data['average']
    print(actualdata)
print("read complete")
```

but it gives me below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 30, in <module>
    data = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 5 (char 6)
```

Below is my text file

```
{
    'info': {
        'symbol': 'ETHUSD',
        'orderid': '20556566',
        'orderlistid': '-1',
        'clientorderid': 'TXgguEidjfF9eLKF',
        'transactiontime': '1619882734',
        'price': '0.00',
        'origqty': '0.00500',
        'executedQty': '0.005000',
        'commutativeQuoteQty': '143.06',
        'status': 'Filled',
        'timeInforce': 'GTC',
        'type': 'MARKET',
        'side': 'buy',
        'fills': [{
            'price': '2861.34',
            'qty': '0.030',
            'comission': '0.0001',
            'comissionAsset': 'BNB',
            'tradeid': '5722834'
        }, {
            'price': '2761.23',
            'qty': '0.019',
            'comission': '0.0001',
            'comissionAsset': 'BNB',
            'tradeid': '5722834'
        }]
    },
    'id': '2044343',
    'clientorderid': 'TXgguEidjfF9eLKF',
    'timestamp': '1619882734',
    'datetime': '2021-06-10T20:21:234',
    'lasttradetimestamp': None,
    'symbol': 'ETHUSD',
    'type': 'MARKET',
    'timeInforce': 'GTC',
    'postonly': 'false',
    'side': 'buy',
    'price': '2861.23',
    'stopprice': 'None',
    'amount': 0.05,
    'cost': 143.06,
    'average': 2861.23,
    'filled': 0.05,
    'remaining': 0.0,
    'status': 'closed',
    'fee': {
        'cost': 0.00013,
        'currency': 'BNB'
    },
    'trades': [{
        'info': {
            'price': '2861.17',
            'qty': '0.0330',
            'comission': '0.0001',
            'commissionAsset': 'BNB',
            'tradeid': '2383487'
        },
        'timestamp': None,
        'datetime': None,
        'symbol': 'ETHUSD',
        'id': None,
        'order': None,
        'type': None,
        'side': None,
        'takerOrMaker': None,
        'price': 2861.23,
        'amount': 0.034,
        'cost': 87.534,
        'fee': {
            'cost': 0.0034,
            'currency': 'BNB'
        }
    }, {
        'info': {
            'price': '2861.23',
            'qty': '0.0019',
            'comission': '0.0023',
            'comissionAsset': 'BNB',
            'tradeid': '453233'
        },
        'timestamp': None,
        'datetime': None,
        'symbol': 'ETHUSD',
        'id': None,
        'order': None,
        'type': None,
        'side': None,
        'takerOrMaker': None,
        'price': 2861.39,
        'amount': 0.01941,
        'cost': 55.53,
        'fee': {
            'cost': 6.737,
            'currency': 'BNB'
        }
    }]
}
```

I am trying to get the "average" value and the JSON response is received from binance api
The response is received using ccxt library and I am trying to print the order that got executed and save the response in json format in text file Any help would be appreciated

I am a bit new to the python so please bear with me here

Thanks in advance. Have a great day :)

Comment: If your file does indeed contain single-quotes, then it's not valid JSON. In fact, your file looks more like the `repr` of a python dict than json. You might wanna `literal_eval` it instead of `json.load`

Comment: @rdas Can you please show me how I can get the value of average using the method you mentioned, considering I will not be able to change the response I receive. I will be transferring the same to file and trying to retrieve 'average' value from it. I tried looking up but couldn't wrap my head around it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need double-quotes for it to be valid JSON.

There are JSON validator and beautification web sites you can try.
jsonlint.com is one of them, for example.

Comment: Hi @Ben , This is the format I am receiving from the server and I am saving it as it is in a text file. Is there any way to retrieve the value of 'average' so that I can use it for further calculations in my code. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Let me ask if you are receiving a text object, or a `dict`. If it's a `dict`, you'll have to do something along the lines of `json.dump('filename.json', obj)` to store it in a form that'll be parsed properly by a JSON parser.

Comment: Another key difference between a Python object, and a JSON object is that there is no `None`, but it has to be `null` within the JSON.

I replaced `'` with `"` and `None` with `null`, and ran it through the JSON lint program and it read it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Thanks, Ben for helping I just had to use `dump` to format everything and then `load` works perfectly. Silly me Thanks all for the help and have a great day ahead :)